# Papyrus install on Eclipse Helios (3.6)

Tags: eclipse, uml, helios

I have just downloaded the latest Eclipse Java EE Helios 3.6.2.  When I attempt to install Papyrus using the Eclipse Marketplace through Yoxos, I get the following dependency error:

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Papyrus UML Modeler 1.12.3.200912231359
>   (com.cea.papyrus.feature.feature.group 1.12.3.200912231359)   Software
>   currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers
>   1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110218-0812)   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       EMF Ecore 2.5.0.v200906151043 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.5.0.v200906151043)
>       EMF Ecore 2.6.1.v20100914-1218 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.6.1.v20100914-1218)
>       EMF Ecore 2.6.0.v20100614-1136 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.6.0.v20100614-1136)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Papyrus UML Modeler 1.12.3.200912231359 (com.cea.papyrus.feature.feature.group 1.12.3.200912231359)
>       To: com.cea.papyrus.ocl.interpreter [1.12.3.200912231359]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: com.cea.papyrus.ocl.interpreter 1.12.3.200912231359 (com.cea.papyrus.ocl.interpreter 1.12.3.200912231359)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.ocl.ecore [1.1.0,2.0.0)   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110218-0812 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110218-0812)

Has anyone been able to install Papyrus on Eclipse 3.6.2 successfully?

Answer (score 2):

Use: [Papyrus Build Site](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/releases/helios)
and make sure that your available sites include helios to resolve all missing requirements

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that the Papyrus plugin you are trying to install requires Eclipse Galileo (EMF 2.5 as opposed to EMF 2.6). You will either need to go back to the older Eclipse release or inquire with the providers of Papyrus plugin about Helios support.

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of Papyrus available: one from www.papyrusuml.org that is supports only Eclipse 3.5 and before, and a newer one from http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/. The latter one supports 3.6 and newer.

According to the error message, the version from the Yoxos site is the older one (it uses the com.cea.papyrus package names instead of the org.eclipse ones.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with 64-bit version of Eclipse Helios.

Comment: Sorry, I did not test it using that system - I'm having a Mac. :D