# Install AGX (agx.me) Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse

Every time I try to install the [AGX Eclipse Plugin](http://agx.me/start/eclipse.html#installing-eclipse-agx) I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: AGX 1.2.2 (org.eclipse.agx.feature.group 1.2.2)
  Missing requirement: AGX 1.2.2 (org.eclipse.agx 1.2.2) requires 'package org.eclipse.papyrus.wizards 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AGX 1.2.2 (org.eclipse.agx.feature.group 1.2.2)
    To: org.eclipse.agx [1.2.2]
```

Galileo 3.5.2
Papyrus 1.12

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try installing the missing papyrus plugin first. Try one of the following update sites listed **[here](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/updates/index.php)**.

I could not find an update site for Ganyemede. Perhaps that is the problem ?

Also, from **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5363119/325742)** answer :

> There are two versions of Papyrus available: one from
>   www.papyrusuml.org that is supports only Eclipse 3.5 and before, and a
>   newer one from http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/. The
>   latter one supports 3.6 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

Works actually, I don't know why...
I use current versions

- Eclipse Kepler
- Papyrus 0.10.0
- PyDev 2.8.1
- Python 2.7.5